How to edit a Power BI report when it can't be opened due to many-to-many relationships
I have a Power BI Dashboard that I built and modified many times. The last time I made a revision I saved it and all worked fine.  However, now when I try to open it I get the "Unable to open document...This file uses many-to-many relationships...etc."  I believe it is perhaps due to the fact that I added an Invoke Function on my last revision.  Anyway, the issue is probably due to the fact that I am using an older version of Power Bi Desktop.
I have tried updating the Power BI to the latest Power BI Desktop version (Optimized for Power BI Report Server - May 2023) and I get the same response of not be able to open.  I was able to install the latest version of Power BI (not optimized for the report server) and get the file to open, however when I make the needed change and save it, try to upload it I get an error the report was created with a recent version of Power BI Desktop that is not supported by this server.
So, what I am hoping is to find a way to open the pbix, remove the Invoked Function, and save it back to the report server.  Of course, I am trying to avoid having to rebuild the report.  Any ideas or thoughts would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

It sounds like you created the report with the Report Server (RS) version but then updated with the non-RS version and added the Many-to-Many relationships so it wouldn't work with RS versions. I don't think there's a way to revert it to work with the RS version. - just a lot of copy/paste between a new one. It may have worked if you had used an older non-RS version to remove the many to many.
